# div replacing everything after it, AJAX, PHP, JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Using ajax, I'm trying to display what is being selected on a div, and it's working, but everything after the div gets replaced by the div's output. I don't know why it's happening or how to fix it. If you know, please let me know.

> test1.php

```
<?php

include('ajax.php');

echo "<select name = 'select' onchange = 'ajax(\"test2.php\",\"select\",\"select\",\"output\")'>";

echo "<option value = '1'> one </option>";
echo "<option value = '2'> two </option>";
echo "<option value = '3'> three </option>";

echo "</select>";

echo "<div id = 'output'>";

echo "text";

?>
```

> test2.php

```
<?php

$select = $_POST['select'];
echo $select;

?>
```

> ajax.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function ajax(url,type,theName,id) {

      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: { select: $(type+'[name='+theName+']').val()},
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             document.getElementById( id ).innerHTML = data;
           }

      });

}

</script>
```

Comment: Why you doing this `<div id = 'output'/>`, should be `<div id = 'output'></div>`

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali Oops.

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali If I change onchange to onload, it doesn't work when the page first gets loaded. Why does that happen?

Comment: as far i know, there is no onload event on a select element.

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali It would be useful if they have that, or something similar. Do you know any work-around this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80725/discussion-between-norlihazmey-ghazali-and-frosty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I testing your code in my pc and it worked. But after change this `echo "<div id = 'output'>";` into this `echo "<div id = 'output'></div>";`, the output only show inside div block and everything after the div gets not replaced.

If you want something similar to onload, just use trigger function to trigger the onchange event after page load like so :

```
 function ajax(url,type,theName,id) {

  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: { select: $(type+'[name='+theName+']').val()},
       error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
       success:function(data) {
         document.getElementById( id ).innerHTML = data;
       }

  });

 }

$(function(){
  $('select[name="select"]').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Anyway to pass in 'select' type, and 'select' name through the parameters?

Comment: Yes you can, but by using body onload. Call the function that pass the paramater into ajax function.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing div tag.